# Is there any Geogebra application for OSX?

Tags: macos, applications

I just can find geogebra app for iPad. How can I find it for my MacBook?

Comment: Have you ever thought about Grapher.

Comment: @Mattia Yes I use it but [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/download) is more powerful and has more options. Specially geometric methods that visually accessible on [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/download).

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org) web site? Available versions are listed in the [download section](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/de/download/) .

Answer (score -4):

Youll find it on the geogebra sit only to find out it doesnt work on an apple

Comment: You mean this app, which is for OS X? … https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geogebra/id845142834